Zk Roll ups - Security
1
We all know that zk rollup uses zk-snark to prove the state transition is valid.
But, now consider that if a malicious relayer creats a proof using incomplete transactions in a batch (e.g. relayer collects 3 transaction tx1, tx2, tx3 but only use tx1 and tx2 to generate zk proof and new state). For the contract, it checks proof and says: okay, it's valid, I'll take it. However, the proof only implies the existence of tx1 and tx2, and the state transition is also based on this.
In this way, the tx3 actually is not included in the new state.
Is it possible to attack? Maybe there is some zk-snark technique issue in it...

The basis of any ZK protocol is that it is not easy to create a 'fake' proofs.
In your example it is correct to create a proof that only includes tx1 and tx2. In that case the creator of tx3 can verify his transaction wasn't included in the proof.
It is unfeasible with current technology to create a fake proof that can convince tx3 creator that it is included, but it is not part of the state transition.

You're right in saying that for the blockchain everything is valid. The relayer/sequencer can decide to not include tx3 in the bundle and ignore it.
If you're asking how can tx3's user outcome this censorship, the solution is allowing users to send txs directly to the contract on L1.
